# googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnHost' permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have given my user both my admin user and the service account user the "Compute Shared VPC Admin" role at the organization level, but I can't seem to enable the requested permission.  I also granted the role at the folder level that owns the namidalab-dev-networks project.  When selecting the namidalab-dev-networks project in the IAM & Admin console UI, the "Compute Shared VPC Admin" option is not available for my admin user and service account user.

How can I grant this role to the project?

Terraform output:

```
...
Step #1 - "Apply": google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.host: Creating...
Step #1 - "Apply": 
Step #1 - "Apply": Error: Error enabling Shared VPC Host "namidalab-dev-networks": googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnHost' permission for 'projects/namidalab-dev-networks', forbidden
Step #1 - "Apply": 
Step #1 - "Apply":   on main.tf line 87, in resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "host":
Step #1 - "Apply":   87: resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "host" {
```

[My Organization, folder and project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSt7B.png)

[Organization configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZiZI.png)

[Folder configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHUqf.png)

[Project configuration - Compute Shared VPC Admin role is no longer available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ72q.png)

[Unable to add Compute Shared VPC Admin here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaU1q.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud recommends that the Shared VPC Admin be the owner of the shared VPC host project.

You need to add the role `roles/compute.xpnAdmin` to the service account that Terraform is using. That is the only role that I am aware of that contains the permission `compute.organizations.enableXpnHost`. I noticed that you mentioned this role in your question, but I think you have it at the wrong level or the wrong project. This should be granted at the organization level or at the VPC Host Project level.

[Compute Shared VPC Admin Role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.xpnAdmin)

This role can be added at the Organization level by the Organization Admin.

Comment: I have added some screen shots to my original question.  I'm think I have configured it as you described, but I'm still getting the Terraform error.

Comment: @SteveMunini - Are you running Terraform as part of Cloud Build? The other screenshots show IAM User accounts that Terraform does not use unless you setup `gcloud auth application-default login`. If you are running Terraform from your desktop, which account did you set up for its permissions?

Comment: Yes, this error is occurring from Cloud Build.  I was instructed to use `gcloud auth login --update-adc` from [these instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fda-mystudies/blob/master/deployment/README.md). I tried `gcloud auth application-default login` and retrying the Terraform script from Cloud Build, but I'm getting the same error.  How can I learn which account is being used from within Cloud Build?

Comment: I was able to locate the service account being used by finding the error in the Logs Explorer.  It is 1033771270852@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com, but I'm unsure how to grant that user Compute Shared VPC Admin.  The UI prohibits adding that role.

Comment: Make a note of the email address for the Cloud Build service account. Go to the Google Cloud Console GUI -> IAM & Admin -> IAM. Switch to the Organization or Folder (in the toolbar) instead of the project. Click "ADD". Enter the service account email address as the "New members". For the role select "Compute Shared VPC Admin". Note: The Cloud Build service account might already be present in the IAM section. If so, edit the entry instead of adding a new entry. Inheritance will grant the service account permission to children (projects) of the organization or folder.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much John.  Really appreciate it!

Comment: @SteveMunini - You are welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: Great! Also, check out https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#nominating_shared_vpc_admins_for_the_organization

Answer (score 4):

FYI, Up to the moment of writing this note & according to the docs https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#terraform.

If you've set the role `roles/compute.xpnAdmin` to the terraform service account **on the folder level** (not on organization level)

You need to use `google-beta` provider explicitly while describing your Shared VPC in terraform script

Otherwise, you will still encounter `Error 403: Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnHost' permission for 'projects/YOUR-PROJECT', forbidden`