# Error 403: Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnHost' permission for project when trying to set up shared VPC via terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, vpc

I am trying to set-up a shared VPC host project with terraform and I get

```
│ Error: Error enabling Shared VPC Host "master-vpc": googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnHost' permission for 'projects/master-vpc', forbidden
│
│   with google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.host,
│   on main.tf line 282, in resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "host":
│  282: resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "host" {
```

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700942/googleapi-error-403-required-compute-organizations-enablexpnhost-permission) that matches exactly my premise, but I can't seem to follow their solution as they are using some service account linked to a cloud run environment, which is not my case. I use a `terraform-admin` service account that has "organization admin rigths" cf. Image 1 [image: Image 1]

Since `terraform-admin` is the one creating resources through `terraform` (that i run locally via an account key), it should have ample permissions to add the resource `google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project`.

Here are the permissions I further assigned to the accounts `network-admin` (The account that I want to manage the VPC with) and the `terraform-admin` the general infrastructure super-admin.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "master-vpc-owner-role" {
  project = google_project.master-vpc.project_id
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.master-vpc-network-admin.email}"
  role    = "roles/owner"
}
resource "google_project_iam_member" "master-vpc-project-iam-admin-role" {
  project = google_project.master-vpc.project_id
  role    = "roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.master-vpc-network-admin.email}"
}
# roles/compute.xpnAdmin does not seem to cascade to the project
resource "google_folder_iam_member" "net-ops-folder-compute-xpnAdmin-role-for-net-admin" {
  folder = google_folder.net-ops.name
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.master-vpc-network-admin.email}"
  role    = "roles/compute.xpnAdmin"
}

# Create the shared VPC
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "host" {
  # project = google_project.master-vpc.project_id
  project = "${var.project_master_vpc.project_id}"
}
```

Could somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Is the fact that I'm running `terraform apply` locally somehow use the authenticated account via **gcloud auth** ?

FYI, in order to apply the infrastructure changes to my organization, I use a credentials' file

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file(var.credentials_file)
  region      = var.region
  zone        = var.zone
}
```

- I can't seem to assign the role `"roles/compute.xpnAdmin"` to the `master-vpc`, which is why I assign it to the parent folder `Net-ops`, but the error "requires" the permission on 'projects/master-vpc'. What am I missing?
- Is enabling this role on the `Net-ops` folder level sufficient, or do I have to put it in the organization level? (I'm not sure if that's a good idea either, as it would grant the `network-admin` some organization-level actions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role `roles/compute.xpnAdmin` needs to be set at the organization's level... Which means the `terraform-admin`, which handles the creation of resources via terraform, needs to have this role.

Here's how to grant it :

```
# On the organization level :
# "roles/compute.xpnAdmin" to create the VPC
resource "google_organization_iam_member" "org-compute-xpnAdmin-role-for-terraform-admin" {
  org_id = <your organization's ID>
  role   = "roles/compute.xpnAdmin"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.terraform_infra_admin.email}"
}

# Create the shared VPC
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "host" {
  # project = google_project.master-vpc.project_id
  project = var.project_master_vpc.project_id
}
```

This of course means that in this case, the organization's infrastructure  administrator is also the one creating the VPC.

Answer (score 2):

The Service account used in Terraform should be the same used in GCP. So this is your terraform-admin, and this account needs to have the role  "roles/compute.xpnAdmin" at organization level as Imad mentioned. This is because this role gives permissions to manage shared VPC host projects, and Google recommends that the shared VPC Admin be the owner of the shared VPC host project, as commented in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.xpnAdmin)